# Catch-all value for mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if there is a catch-all value I can use in search queries for Mongodb that would return all entries in the database?

Give a "Story" model, I know the code to find all stories is "Story.find({}).exec()". What I'm struggling to figure out is if I needed to pass in a parameter -> "Story.find({termId: someValue}).exec()", is there a catch all someValue like "*" that I could pass in that would return all the entries?

The reason I need to find this is I'm trying to overload the following function, and in some cases, I'll pass a termId and would like to limit the search, while in another case, I would call someFn without an argument, and would like it to return all the entries.

The Q.all function code is relatively complex, and I would prefer not to divide it into if-else blocks

```
function someFn(termId) {
   Q.all([Q.nbind(..., Story.find({termId: termId}).exec()...]).spread()}
}


// Not so elegant solution I'm trying to avoid
function someFn(termId) {
  if (typeof termId === 'undefined'){
    Q.all([Q.nbind(..., Story.find({}).exec()...]).spread()}
  }
  else {
    Q.all([Q.nbind(..., Story.find({termId: termId}).exec()...]).spread()}
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt a catchall value make the condition you entered useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a wildcard value you can use to match any `termId` value, but you can make this more manageable by building up your query object programmatically:

```js
function someFn(termId) {
  var query = {};
  if (typeof termId !== 'undefined'){
    query.termId = termId;
  }
  Q.all([Q.nbind(..., Story.find(query).exec()...]).spread()}
}
```

Comment: Wow, I completely didn't think of that. Very nice

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `termId` query value to `{$exists: true}` as a default, and then override in your function.

So by default, your query will look like this:

```
{termId: {$exists: true}}
```

Which will return all the documents which have `termId` field defined, which will turn out to be all the documents. And as soon as you pass another value, it will override the `{$exists: true}` and work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using a ternary operator inside of your mongodb query.

Below is an example I used for searching for users based on their country. It allows you to query the DB for either a specific country, or all countries based on the search term. This can also be scaled to add extra conditions accordingly.

```
let {country} = req.body

const students = await studentModel.find({country: country === 'all' ? {$exists: true} : country })
```